# cannot access files on server in web browser

Tags: php, logging, shared-hosting

## Scenario

---

I have various files on a shared host, including log files (.log) and PHP files which my web pages communicate with after form submission

Recently (last hour or so), I am no longer able to view/access files on the server via a web browser like I could before.

I can still edit files and place new files on the server with an FTP client.

## Question

---

Does anyone know why can't I access files on my shared hosting with a web browser anymore?

Comment: Permissions, you hard coded the full path instead of using relative and the hoster changed the path (happened to me with 1and1), problem at the providers infra, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its most likely going to be a permission issue or script does not know about the files (wrong file path). Make sure that the script can see the files and is able to read them from a disk

Comment: Maybe. There are no scripts running on the log files though - I used to be able to view them in a browser, but now I can't. Maybe Nic is right and I need to investigate if the provider has changed path names.

Comment: Make sure your web server can see them. It seems like permission issues 
What OS is the shared host on ?
Maybe just restart the WebServer application

Comment: shared host OS = linux

Comment: just run in terminal "ls -alrt" on a log files and see what permission they have and who is the owner